# Remove the Index from CSV and print Complete Row

Tags: python, pandas, csv

> I am trying to read from a csv file using pandas and write the 'Title' Column in a text file .
> This is the Code i Wrote :

```
import pandas as pd 

csv_data = pd.read_csv('testing.csv' , usecols = ['title'])
csv_data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(csv_data)

f = open("test.txt", "w")
f.write(str(csv_data))
f.close()
```

> This is the Output i got :

```
    title                                                 
0  NIT Silchar Recruitment 2020 for Junior Resear...
1  Dr. B. Borooah Cancer Institute Recruitment 20...
2  Assam University Recruitment 2020 for Junior R...
```

> How to remove the title heading name . **Also row is printed in "dot" "dot"** . How to fix it ?

> And **is it possible to remove the Indexes** which pandas create automatically at the start ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to_string() method from pandas, as in [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html)

```py
import pandas as pd 

csv_data = pd.read_csv('testing.csv' , usecols = ['title'])
csv_data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

string_df = csv_data.to_string(header=False, index=False)
print(string_df)

f = open("test.txt", "w")
f.write(string_df)
f.close()
```

Comment: will this remove the dot dot dot and write the full text

Comment: Yes, I think it will print the full line.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
    import pandas as pd
    csv_data = pd.read_csv('testing.csv' ,usecols = ['title'], index_col=0)
    f = open("test.txt","w")
    for i in csv_data.index:
        f.write(i+"\n")
    f.close()
```

This will store the data in only the Title column to the text file. Hope this helped!

Comment: will this remove the dot dot dot and write the full text

Comment: Yess it will print the full line, with each title on a new line in the text file